# c++ find any string from a list in another string

Tags: c++

What options do I have to find any string from a list in another string ?

With s being an std::string, I tried

```
s.find("CAT" || "DOG" || "COW" || "MOUSE", 0);
```

I want to find the first one of these strings and get its place in the string ; so if s was "My cat is sleeping\n" I'd get 3 as return value.

```
boost::to_upper(s);
```

was applied (for those wondering).

Comment: Seems like a regexp could do it. You can use `|` as separator. That is, your regexp can be `cat|dog|cow|mouse`.

Comment: You can just iterate through your strings in a loop and call find for each one.

Comment: @AlexPetrenko Not very optimized, is it ? There are many strings and many parameters to search, I've simplified it here for the sake of understanding

Comment: @FabioTurati I am limited to C++98 -_-'

Comment: @Saryk Then I think you should try with boost. I am not so familiar with it, and I don't even have it installed here, but I think just a few adaptations should be needed. You can use my answer as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a regex.

I don't think there's a way to get the position of a match directly, so first you have to search for the regex, and if there is a match you can search for that string. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "My cat is sleeping\n";
    smatch m;
    regex animal("cat|dog|cow|mouse");

    if (regex_search (s,m,animal)) {
        cout << "Match found: " << m.str() << endl;
        size_t match_position = s.find(m.str());

        // In this case it is always true, but in general you might want to check
        if (match_position != string::npos) {
            cout << "First animal found at: " << match_position << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may convert your search cases to a DFA. It is the most efficient way of doing it.

states:

```
nil, c, ca, cat., d, do, dog., co, cow., m, mo, mou, mous, mouse.
```

transition table:

```
state | on | goto
nil   | c  | c
nil   | d  | d
nil   | m  | m
c     | a  | ca
c     | o  | co
d     | o  | do
m     | o  | mo
ca    | t  | cat.
co    | w  | cow.
do    | g  | dog.
mo    | u  | mou
mou   | s  | mous
mous  | e  | mouse.
*     | *  | nil
```

You may express this using a lot of intermediary functions. Using a lot of switches. Or using enum to represent states and a mapping to represent the transitions.

If your test case list is dynamic or grows too big, then a manually hardcoding the states will nor suffice for you. However, as you can see, the rule to make the states and the transitions is very simple.

Comment: It is an interesting exercise. Otherwise, don't waste your time unless you are sure you need this level of optimisation.